# IBM Watson TextToSpeech - cannot read property .pipe of undefined

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I have the following code, straight from the documentation:

```
var TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to- 
speech/v1');
var fs = require('fs');

var textToSpeech = new TextToSpeechV1({
iam_apikey: '---myapikey---',
url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/'
});

var synthesizeParams = {
text: 'Hello world, you dummy ass',
accept: 'audio/wav',
voice: 'en-US_AllisonVoice'
};

// Pipe the synthesized text to a file. 
textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams).on('error', function(error) {
console.log(error);
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('hello_world.wav'));
```

when I run it it gives the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/tjbotcz_lite $ sudo node ttstest.js
/home/pi/Desktop/tjbotcz_lite/ttstest.js:16
textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams).on('error', function(error) {
                                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Desktop/tjbotcz_lite/ttstest.js:16:42)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
```

Any clues why? I have the same issue with TJBot, so I tried a simple example from documentation and voila - the same error.
When I use my old service (with username and password, not api key) it works fine. I have the new version of watson-cloud library (3.13.1).

Thanks for any hints.
Regards,
Jan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works for me and generating an **audio.wav** file using the Text-to-Speech API Key

```
var TextToSpeechV1 = require('watson-developer-cloud/text-to-speech/v1');
var fs = require('fs');

var textToSpeech = new TextToSpeechV1({
  iam_apikey: '<API_KEY>',
  url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api'
});

var synthesizeParams = {
  text: 'Hello world',
  accept: 'audio/wav',
  voice: 'en-US_AllisonVoice'
};

textToSpeech
  .synthesize(synthesizeParams, function(err, audio) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    textToSpeech.repairWavHeader(audio);
    fs.writeFileSync('audio.wav', audio);
    console.log('audio.wav written with a corrected wav header');
});
```

**Updated** the code snippet and this works

Comment: Thanks, i tried with "apikey" parameter (although they have iam_apikey in documentation: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/text-to-speech/api/v1/node.html?node#synthesize  as Node example), it creates an empty wav file :(

Answer (score 4):

I looked here for help but the docs there are definitely wrong. I was able to solve this by using `audio.result.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('audio.wav')`

Comment: That worked! Generally, I've found that when working with streams, log the response and what you thought was a stream turns out to be a JSON object and one of the properties is the stream, `response.data` or `response.results`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this using promises so I can wait for the audio file to be completely saved and then do further processing. Also, as others stated, the documentation was wrong and the correct way is to use audio.**result**.pipe() instead of audio.pipe().

```
function synthesize_audio(text, mp3Path) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`> Synthesizing audio from text: "${text}"`)

    const textToSpeech = new TextToSpeechV1({
      authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
        apikey: apikey,
      }),
      url: apiUrl,
    });

    const synthesizeParams = {
      text: text,
      accept: 'audio/mp3',
      voice: 'pt-BR_IsabelaV3Voice',
    };

    textToSpeech.synthesize(synthesizeParams)
    .then(audio => {    
      audio.result
            .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(mp3Path))
            .on('finish', resolve)
            .on('error', reject);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error:', err);
    });
  });
}
```

You can then await and do what you want:

```
 await synthesize_audio(text, outputPath)
  .then(() => {
    //then you can safely do what you want
  })
}
```